# How do I create a customised box image packed with ansible for a current vagrant box?

Tags: vagrant, ansible

I thought I might ask, I currently am using a vagrant box and every time I start up the box using `vagrant up` I always have to download ansible along side it as the vagrant box uses ansible local provisioner. So could someone explain to me how I could pack my current vagrant box into a customised box image packed along with ansible so I do not have to keep on downloading the package?

I know I need to use [Vagrant Packer](https://www.packer.io/intro/getting-started/vagrant.html) but could someone explain the process of using it for the way I need?

Thanks,

George Barlow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have the following choice :

1. find a box that does this job already, https://app.vagrantup.com/boxes/search?page=2&provider=&q=ansible&sort=downloads&utf8=✓
2. update your current box and [repackage it](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/cli/box.html#box-repackage) so you'll use the updated box further on
3. as you mention, use packer, in this case find packer templates that creates VM with ansible installation, you could look some of [those repo](https://github.com/geerlingguy?utf8=%E2%9C%93&tab=repositories&q=packer&type=&language=) or search GitHub for other script that will do your job

Comment: Thank you, I found a packer that installs ansible from a file from one of them repos more specifically https://github.com/geerlingguy/ansible-role-packer-debian